# Angular class property to constant variable

Tags: angular

I have assigned a class property to constant variable. The constant is changeable and class property is changing when I changed constant.

```
    export class SampleClass implements OnInit {
        name = "a";

        onclick() {
            const tempName = this.name;
            tempName = "b"; // error
            console.log(this.name); // a
        }
    }
```

[Edit]
The same scenario as I asked above,

```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      name = [
        {"option":"Never",            "weight":0},
        {"option":"Sometimes",        "weight":1},
        {"option":"Many time",        "weight":2},
        {"option":"Most of the time", "weight":3},
        {"option":"All the time",     "weight":4}
      ];

      ngOnInit() {
        const tempName = this.name;
        tempName[0].weight = 10; // constant is changing

        console.log(this.name); // this.name[0].weight also set to 10
        console.log(tempName); 
      }
    }
```

How to unlink them?

please check this [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-project-rramzb)

Comment: Is this code compiling? It should throw a compile error when trying to reassign a value to a `const`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Apart from the reassigning a `const` mentioned above, primitives (including strings) are copied by value, not reference, and `tempName = "b";` won't change the value of `this.name`.

Comment: Just to support @mbojko comment, you can check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-varaible-reference?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I have removed my answer, jumped the gun thanks for pointing it out :-)

Comment: @lealceldeiro Please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-project-rramzb
same scenario but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all you answers. I got the solution to my problem!

Actually what I did is assigned the non-primitive object to the const variable. In javascript, always non-primitive variables assign only the reference (address of object) not value.

if I want to copy whole object as new object to another variable, my code should be

```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      name = [
        {"option":"Never",            "weight":0},
        {"option":"Sometimes",        "weight":1},
        {"option":"Many time",        "weight":2},
        {"option":"Most of the time", "weight":3},
        {"option":"All the time",     "weight":4}
      ];

      ngOnInit() {
        let tempName = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.name));
        tempName[0].weight = 10;

        console.log(this.name); // this.name[0].weight stays 0
        console.log(tempName); 
      }
    }
```

Detailed **Assign by value vs reference** ref: [Here](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0)

Answer (score 3):

@mbojko is right in his comment:

> Apart from the reassigning a **const** mentioned above, primitives (including strings) are copied by value, not reference, and `tempName = "b"`; won't change the value of this.name

First of all, it won't compile at all and even if it does for some reason, it won't change the value of `this.name`.

[image]

Comment: I want to copy non-primitives only by values not reference. What I have to do

Answer (score 1):

there is no way

> this.name

gets changed due to the code you have posted.And constant variable is not changeable also you have two different variables as tempName  & tempname.

Comment: I don't see two variables, just a `tempName`? Where did you see `tempname`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Same scenario not working here https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-project-rramzb please check it

Answer (score 1):

Your example is misleading as in the stackblitz, the const you're overriding is an array. To split the link you'll have to do this;

This:

```
const tempName = this.name;
```

Becomes:

```
const tempName = [...this.name];
```

This will "unlink" them

Comment: I just updated the code in stackblitz nothing changed please check

Comment: im not sure what you're trying to do, there maybe other errors. You can test that this code has the desired effect if before your console log, change something in the array, it will only affect one of them. Put this ` this.name[0] = {"option": "were", "weight": 19};` above your first console (line 29) and compare the difference

What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question. Hope you'll get what I am trying to do